# HTML drop down menu secondary links are automatically showing. i want to make them visible on hover

Tags: html

HTML drop down menu secondary links are automatically showing. i want to make them visible

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpOZPy)

**HTML**

Dropdown Menu - WordPress Style

```
<h1>The Title of your Blog</h1>
<nav>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Front Page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sample Page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About The Tests</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Page Image Alignment</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page Markup And Formatting</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Clearing Floats</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page with comments</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page with comments disabled</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Level 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Level 2a</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Level 3a</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Level 3b</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Level 3c</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Level 2b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Level 2c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page B</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav><head>
  <title>Dropdown Menu - WordPress Style</title>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<h1>The Title of your Blog</h1>
<nav>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Front Page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sample Page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About The Tests</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Page Image Alignment</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page Markup And Formatting</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Clearing Floats</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page with comments</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page with comments disabled</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Level 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Level 2a</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Level 3a</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Level 3b</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Level 3c</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Level 2b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Level 2c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page B</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

nav {
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  font: 12px bold;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #2d2c2c;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  background: #555;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  background: #555;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #666;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

nav a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

nav a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

nav a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: inherit;
}

nav:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
}

nav ul ul ul li:first-child {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

nav ul ul li {
  min-width: 170px;
  float: none;
  background-color: #333;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}

nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: inherit;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avVZNp

I've added

```
nav ul li ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover ul li {
   display: block;
}
```

Full CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

nav {
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  font: 12px bold;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #2d2c2c;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  background: #555;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  background: #555;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #666;
}

nav ul li ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

nav a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

nav a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

nav a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: inherit;
}

nav:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
}

nav ul ul ul li:first-child {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

nav ul ul li {
  min-width: 170px;
  float: none;
  background-color: #333;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}

nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: inherit;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
}
```